# Many-to-many dimensions in a datawarehouse using Mondrian schema

Tags: jruby, pentaho, data-warehouse, olap, mondrian

I'm using [mondrian-olap](https://github.com/rsim/mondrian-olap) JRuby gem to query a datawarehouse using Mondrian library. I'm trying to build the OLAP schema but i'm having trouble setting a dimension composed by a many-to-many relationship.

I have a product with many categories, and so I created a table Product, a table ProductCategory and a table Category. The number of products is always increasing and so, using a single ProductCategory table seems a bit risky to me.

The Mondrian documentation was inconclusive for me, and all existing schema examples with a snowflake schema use only a single relationship table (like ProductCategory) and not a many-to-many combination of ones.

Is it possible to represent a many-to-many relationship using a Mondrian schema? Is there a better way to set this relationship?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this problem!

Comment: Im interested too. Kimball says you should use a bridge table which I tried but turned out mondrian didn't deal with it properly.  So I fear currently this is not possible.  Mondrian4 has been wildly changed in the cube spec area but I don't specifically see anything to help this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mondrian does not support many-to-many relationships. This is a [feature](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-1572) that we have already started looking into, but there are no ETA as of now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will use the supported snowflake schema for now (with a 1-N relationship dimension)